# Unable to pass annotation data to tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkannotation

EDITED QUESTION:

I'm trying to take annotations created in map view (with title/subtitle) and push all annotations on my map to a tableview showing the list with title/subtitle.

I have a RegionAnnotation.h/.m NSObject file that works the reverse geocoding I need to populate the pins on my MapViewController. This works just fine. I do a long press which create a pin and the title and subtitle show up and the reverse geocoding works.

Now I want to push the pin data to a tableview list. I have tried calling the region annotation information within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I use `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` in order to get the correct format for the cell to populate the title and subtitle.  However when I call the following:

```
if (cell == nil){
    NSLog(@"if cell");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

CLPlacemark *pins = [self.annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
RegionAnnotation *annotation = [[RegionAnnotation alloc] initWithLocationIdentifier:(NSString *)pins];
cell.textLabel.text = annotation.title;
```

I only get the title, which is this case is "Location Reminder", however, the subtitle information which is the address does not populate the table.  All that shows is the text "subtitle".

How do I populate the cell with both title and subtile information.  I've been working on this for over a month and can't seem to find a solution.  Please help.

Comment: In viewDidLoad the line `[self.annotations addObjectsFromArray:_annotations];` doesn't make sense because _annotations is the ivar behind the annotations property so essentially they point to the same thing.  If the table is supposed to show the pins, why is numberOfRowsInSection returning regions.count?  What does regions have to do with annotations?  In cellForRowAtIndexPath, why are you creating a new RegionAnnotation object?

Comment: You are right about the viewDidLoad, I meant to remove that, thanks. I have .m file called RegionAnnotation which has code that calls the information.  I'll edit the original to show.

Comment: OK but if you already have the annotations on the map view controller, why would you need to create new instances of them in cellForRowAtIndexPath?  Don't the annotations on the map VC already have the title and subtitle set?  Still not clear why you have both regions and annotations in the PinListVC.  How does the map VC create and show the PinListVC?

Comment: Yes, the mapview shows the title and subtitle when the pin is selected. I just don't know how to get that information to show as a list on the table.  I thought since I'm calling the info from the RegionAnnotation file to show on the mapview, then I need to call that same information on the pinlistVC. And there is where I'm stuck.  I shouldn't have to create new instances, just pass the info.  However, I'm not sure how to do that. If I remove the regions count from the viewDidLoad, then my tableview is blank.

Comment: I removed the [self.annotations addObjectsFromArray:_annotations]; still stuck.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: That line was just something strange -- removing it was not a "fix".  The questions from my comment 2 days ago are still relevant and open.  Let me ask another way: Your map VC has annotations and an annotations array.  Your table VC is using a "regions" array as the basis for its row count and data.  Why is the table VC not using the annotations from the map VC?  How does the map VC create and show the table VC?

Comment: Question 1: Regarding "regions" array as the basis for its row count and data. - From my RegionAnnotation.m file I have the  `(id)initWithCLRegion:(CLRegion *)newRegion` where `[self.getAddress]` is called so that is why I was calling a regions array in the viewDidLoad and the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  If I look at the logs, I was grabbing all the data including the address that was geocoded from the long/lat coordinates. But for some reason I could not get that to populate the cell. Question 2: I am not sure how to grab the annotations from the MapViewController.m

Comment: I updated the above question and took out all the code that doesn't relate.  I would still appreciate some help.

Comment: Ok, I'll take another look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments on the latest code posted:

```
CLPlacemark *pins = [self.annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
RegionAnnotation *annotation = [[RegionAnnotation alloc] 
    initWithLocationIdentifier:(NSString *)pins];
```

This doesn't look right.  The `pins` variable is declared as a `CLPlacemark` (which is suspicious in itself because `CLPlacemark` doesn't conform to `MKAnnotation` so why is it in an "annotations" array?) and then it is being casted an `NSString *` which has no relationship to a `CLPlacemark`.  The cast is not going convert `pins` into a string -- it's going to treat the data pointed to by `pins` as if it was a `NSString` (which it isn't).

There are too many other issues, questions and unknowns with the previous code that was posted as well.

---

Instead, I'll give an example of how you might pass the annotations that are on the map view to a table view and show the data in the cells...

- In the `PinListViewController` (the one with the table view), we declare an `NSArray` property to receive and reference the annotations:

  ```
  //in the .h:
  //Don't bother declaring an ivar with the same name.
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *annotations;
  //in the .m:
  @synthesize annotations;
  ```
- Next, in the `MapViewController`, in the place where you want to present/push/show the `PinListViewController`, the code would be something like this:

  ```
  PinListViewController *plvc = [[PinListViewController alloc] init...

  //pass the map view's annotations array...
  plvc.annotations = mapView.annotations;

  [self presentModalViewController:plvc animated:YES];  //or push, etc.

  [plvc release];  //remove if using ARC
  ```

  An important point here is that this example sends the *entire* annotations array.  If you are showing the user's current location using `showsUserLocation = YES` then the array will include that annotation as well.  If you only want to send certain annotations, you'll have to first build a new array containing the ones you want from the map view array and set `plvc.annotations` equal to that new array.  A simple way to do that is to loop through the `mapView.annotations` and if an annotation is one you want to include, add it to the new array using `addObject`.  Another possible issue with using the map view's `annotations` array directly is that if the annotations on the map change (are added/removed) *while* the table view is still showing the annotations list, it will go out of sync and may cause run-time range exceptions.  To avoid that, if necessary, you could set `plvc.annotations` to a copy of the map view's annotations array (ie. `[mapView.annotations copy]`).
- In `PinListViewController`, in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

  ```
  return self.annotations.count;
  ```
- In `PinListViewController`, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

  ```
  //typical dequeue/alloc+init stuff here...
  //assume cell style is set to UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

  id<MKAnnotation> annotation = [self.annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = annotation.title;
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = annotation.subtitle;

  return cell;
  ```

  The `annotation` is declared as `id<MKAnnotation>` so it will work with any type of annotation since the example only needs to show the standard `title` and `subtitle` properties.  If you needed to show custom properties you may have in your custom annotation class, you would use `isKindOfClass` to check if `annotation` is of that type and then you can cast it to that custom class and reference the custom properties.

Comment: Thank you Anna, I did something very similar to your answer before I saw this. The one thing I couldn't get was the title to load but now the addresses are populating the tableviewcontroller.  I'll review the above and add anything that might help and post later to let you know it worked.  Thanks a bunch!